# Accessing methods inside a class into another class

Tags: java, object, creation

I have 3 classes A, B and C. An object for A is created in B and uses some of the methods of A in B using A's object.

C has object of B. Now I want to access one method which is in A from C (a private member of A).

How can I do that?

Comment: there is no access to `private` method outside of the class

Comment: can you change A's code?

Comment: Could you please show a piece of code that demonstrates what you are talking about?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. The title you used is a bit confusing, so I removed the part of the title that was also in the question.

Also, I put paragraphs in your question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Let's call your private method in A that you want to access from C: `method3`.

If `method3` is **private** and you can't change it, then there is no way to do this (as said in Taher's comment).

If `method3` doesn't have to be **private**, then there are two options:

1. You can make `method3` [**protected**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html) and have B [inherit](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html) from A. B's class declaration would look like this: `public class B extends A {`, and the call from C is simply: `b.method3();`.

   - Note: this is only appropriate if the hierarchy makes sense in your program (e.g. class `Wheel` inherits from class `Car`).
2. If you don't want to use inheritance, you can make `method3` [**public**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html) and expose B's A object via a getter. The method would be (in class B):

   ```
   public A getA() {
       return a;
   }
   ```

   And the call: `b.getA().method3();`.

Comment: if so, how can I accesses the functions inside class A to class C(public functions)

Comment: Oh sorry I didn't even answer the question did I? Furthermore my answer was incorrect. I changed my answer.

Comment: If this answers your question please mark it as the accepted answer (green tick under the upvotes).